# Link using <a href=""></a> in HTML Map Tip (QGIS Expression)

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-expression

I am trying to include a link to an external web in the HTML Map Tip window in QGIS. The url is a field in the Attribute Table called "url".
This is my html (the link doesn't work):

```
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">[%name%]</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle">[%owner%]</h6>
    <a href=[% CASE WHEN  "url" = NULL THEN 'https://www.google.com' ELSE "url"  END %]  target="_blank" class="card-link"></a></span>
    
    <ul class="card-list">
        <li class="card-list-item">Capacity(MW): [%capacity_mw%]</li>
        <li class="card-list-item">Estimated Generation(GWh): [%estimated_generation_gwh%]</li>
        <li>[% CASE WHEN  "commissioning_year" = NULL THEN 'Commissioning year: unknown' ELSE 'Commissioning year: '   ||  "commissioning_year" 
END %] </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works right in the Expression Dialog as you see here:
[image]
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `<a href=[% CASE WHEN  "url" IS NULL THEN 'https://www.google.com' ELSE "url"  END %]  target="_blank" class="card-link">click me</a></span>`

I replaced `= null` by `is null`, and of course you need some text to be clicked-on

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten the text. It works rigth also with ```= null```

Comment: @hrd if this answers your question, please accept it - https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers